# Question on whitespaces in h:outputText and h:inputText

Tags: jsf

I am getting issue somthing `h:outputText` and `h:inputText` both are displaying values but they are collapse the multiple whitespaces into single white space

for that i tried with `style="white-space:pre"` but it also not working
so i am adding `&nbsp;` in between strings

```
String str="hi & nbsp jsf"
```

and

`<h:inputtext value="#{bean.str}">`

while displaying it shows in input text box with value "hi & nbsp ;jsf" not "hi jsf"
So, what should i have to do so that that it will display without "& nbsp;"

actually i have put that space between & nbsp; because here it will replaceing with white space

I don't want `<h:outputText>` with `escape="false"` for displaying because at some place i need `h:inputText`. In `h:inputText` there is no option for escape attribute

any other permanent solution for white Space Issue

Comment: If i understand what you need, you can try
value="AAA &#160; BBB"/>. Output is space between AAA and BBB

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and through trial and error was able to get around it by adding a style to my outputText:

```
<h:outputText style="white-space:pre;" value="My Text Here"/>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: but its not working @Dave

Answer (score 0):

the white spaces from outputText are there if you look at the source code.

it sounds like you do not want to escape   but you want to escape everything else, which you cant.
you cant have the cookie and eat it too.

sounds like this is a ui problem that you should handle with html/css